# How to disable warnings about low disk space

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I have a bunch of Session Hosts in a Remote Desktop Services environment.

How can I disable warnings about low disk space?

When the user logs on they see I warning about low disk space for a local disk on one of the local drives of the Session Host.

I don’t want the end-users to see this warning since we have a monitoring infrastructure that takes care of such issues.

Is it possible to remove the warning?

Comment: Fix the low disk space issue?

Comment: @joeqwerty Absolutely! But until that issue is resolved, I don’t want the warning to be exposed to the end-users. On a single-user Windows 10 system, such a warning to the end-user makes a lot of sense. But in an RDS environment, IMHO it would be great if the end-user wasn’t exposed to the warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can disable Low disk space checks by adding this registry value (DWORD, data: 1) `NoLowDiskSpaceChecks`

here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```